# How works the getElementById(str) function (not to know how use it, and yes how are the function steps)?

Tags: javascript

I'd would like to know how is the *getElementById(str)* function steps on javascript.

I want to do a function based on it to get elements by a different way.

Okay, I just want to know the right way how may the function be created.

I already did think that it may use *substr()* to get some element in body, but will the *substr()* be the right way?

Then I'd just like to know about that, what the function do to get the element and its values.

Comment: If you enter `document.getElementById` in the chrome console, you can see it shows `function getElementById() { [native code] }` - ie it's implementation specific as to how it works.  I suspect it's somewhat more sophisticated than parsing the string content of the page, since the browser has the entire DOM available to it.  If you want to select by attributes, take a look at [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById()` is a low-level DOM function, and asking "how it works" is asking the wrong question because that's dependent on the DOM / JS implementation.

It sounds to me what you're trying to do was already solved by several very popular JS libraries, namely jQuery. I suggest you start looking into jQuery's DOM selectors. If you really want to learn, look at how jQuery does it.

Comment: But I want not jQuery because it has many functions that are unneeded and it's much heavy. Plugins are bad, but also are helpful. I just need few functions.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are several minimalistic DOM/CSS selector JS libraries out there. A quick Google search gives http://sizzlejs.com/ for example, and http://www.dustindiaz.com/qwery - I haven't tried any but I'm sure at least some are good). In any case if you want to learn and that's why you want to write your own (usually that's the only good reason), look at their source code.